# Making Word documents independent of their linked templates

Tags: ms-word

At the office we are using several custom Word 2007 / 2010 templates. If we then send out doc files to clients they sometimes appear quite messy and ugly unformatted, as they do not have these templates on their machines.

Is there a way to embed templates into Word documents or kind of "flatten" these documents so they are not depending on the templates anymore and have formatting, images etc. all contained within just the Word doc file without needing the template anymore?

btw: I know printing the doc into a pdf and sending this would be a workaround, but we need to keep it in word, as clients have to be able to edit the documents.

Answer (score 0):

This macro will break the link between a document and its template:

```
Sub DivorceFromTemplate()
    ' Dissassociates the document from its Word Template
    With ActiveDocument
        .UpdateStylesOnOpen = False
        .AttachedTemplate = ""
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Hobbes. But do the styles of the template get applied before it is de-tached?

Comment: No, this just breaks the link. There are some potential problems with automatically updating styles, see http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/UpdateStyles.htm